# 'Required' not firing MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Model :

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Username Required")]
  [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = ":Less than 30 characters")]
  public string name { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }
  public string mob { get; set; }
```

Controller :

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Insert(Employee emp)
    {
        Employee emp1 = new Employee();
        emp1.insert(emp);
        return View();
    }
```

View :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Insert", "Employee", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.mob)

    <input type="submit" value="Register me" />
}
```

When i click submit with empty value of name its not showing "Username Required". Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're missing `Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => ...)` for each

Comment: Or `Html.ValidationSummary`

Comment: Your not including the necessary `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.name)` in your view (and you should be testing for `ModelState.IsValid` before inserting the data.

Comment: Also, you don't check `ModelState.IsValid` before attempting to `Insert`. Hopefuly, your DAL will throw at this.

Comment: Based on this and your last question, I strongly suggest you buy yourself a good book to learn the basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing few things

1) In view you should add `@Html.ValidationSummary` for displaying all the validation error or you can use `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.name)` for showing the error message for specific property.

2) In controller add

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Insert(Employee emp)
     {

      if(!ModelState.IsValid)

        {
          return view(emp)
        }

        Employee emp1 = new Employee();
        emp1.insert(emp);
        return View();
     }
```

to check if modal is invalid then return to the current page with validation errors